# Want to know how many objects are in the overlap of two different subsets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I have a category with certain characteristics (height & weight, defined by np.where) and a different category with other characteristics (if someone is a twin or not & how many siblings, defined by np.where). I want to see how many fall into both categories at the same time (like how many would be in the center if a Venn diagram was made?).

I'm importing columns of a CSV file.
This is what the table looks like:

```
    Child  Inches  Weight Twin  Siblings
0     A      53     100    Y         3
1     B      54     110    N         4
2     C      56     120    Y         2
3     D      58     165    Y         1
4     E      60     150    N         1
5     F      62     160    N         1
6     H      65     165    N         3
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = pd.read_csv(r'~/Downloads/Test3 CVS_Sheet1.csv')
#%%
height = file["Inches"]
weight = file["Weight"]
twin = file["Twin"]
siblings = file["Siblings"]
#%%
area1 = np.where((height <= 60) & (weight <= 150))[0]
#%%
#has two or more siblings (and is a twin)
group_a = np.where((siblings >= 2) & (twin == 'Y'))[0]

#has two or more siblings (and is not a twin)
group_b = np.where((siblings >= 2) & (twin == 'N'))[0]

#has only one sibling (and is twin)
group_c = np.where((siblings == 1) & (twin == 'Y'))[0]

#has only one sibling (and is not a twin)
group_d = np.where((siblings == 1) & (twin == 'N'))[0]
#%%
for i in area1:
    if group_a==True:
        print("in area1 there are", len(i), "children in group_a")
    elif group_b==True:
        print("in area1 there are", len(i), "children in group_b")  
    elif group_c==True:
        print("in area1 there are", len(i), "children in group_c")
    elif group_d==True:
        print("in area1 there are", len(i), "children in group_d")
```

I get the error: "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

I'm hoping for an output like:

```
"in area1 there are 2 children in group_a"
"in area1 there are 1 children in group_b"
"in area1 there are 0 children in group_c"
"in area1 there are 1 children in group_d"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback, as that can help diagnose your issue

Comment: @G.Anderson File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "~box_test1.py", line 54, in <module>
    if group_a==True:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @G.Anderson Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, I would take a slightly different design. You can do this:

```
df['area1'] = np.where((df.Inches <= 60) & (df.Weight <= 150),1,0)
df['group_a'] = np.where((df.Siblings >= 2) & (df.Twin == 'Y'),1,0)
df['group_b'] = np.where((df.Siblings >= 2) & (df.Twin == 'N'),1,0)
df['group_c'] = np.where((df.Siblings == 1) & (df.Twin == 'Y'),1,0)
df['group_d'] = np.where((df.Siblings == 1) & (df.Twin == 'N'),1,0)
```

and the result would look like this:

[image]

From this point you can build your query such that in order to see group_b you would do:

```
df.groupby(['area1'])['group_b'].sum()[1]
```

and you'll have your desired result: 1. You can play with the sum or count to adjust to your table.

finally:

```
for col in df.columns[6:]:
   r = df.groupby(['area1'])[col].sum()[1]
   print ("in area1 there are",r,'children in',col)
```

would yield:

```
in area1 there are 2 children in group_a
in area1 there are 1 children in group_b
in area1 there are 0 children in group_c
in area1 there are 1 children in group_d
```

Comment: I’m not very familiar with pandas. So does what you did edit the CSV table directly?

Comment: @madrose after you read your file with df = pd.read_csv(r'~/Downloads/Test3 CVS_Sheet1.csv') you can write the addition I provided in my answer. (You called it file, I called it df)

Comment: Okay, I see how this works with this set. Thank you! I'm going to try this same method now with my actual 100 x 1200 CSV table. Quick question: What is the purpose of the [1] in "r = df.groupby(['area1'])[col].sum()[1]" ?

Comment: theres a for loop on your dataframe so it can produce the r (result) for each group (the group start from column 6 hence [6:] don't forget that we start counting from 0. The [1] means 2nd item in the group (there's item0 = for all zero result and item1 [1] for the 1ns)

Comment: @mardose cool. Pandas is awesome, a lot to learn but once you get it  - you'll be a ninja :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with i and the looping but this should work

```
import os
import pandas as pd
file_data = pd.read_csv(r'~/Downloads/Test3 CVS_Sheet1.csv')
area1 = file_data[file_data['Inches'] <= 60]
area1 = area1[area1['Weight'] <= 150]

group_a = area1[area1['Siblings'] >= 2]
group_a = group_a[group_a['Twin'] == 'Y']

group_b = area1[area1['Siblings'] >= 2]
group_b = group_b[group_b['Twin'] == 'N']

group_c = area1[area1['Siblings'] == 1]
group_c = group_c[group_c['Twin'] == 'Y']

group_d = area1[area1['Siblings'] == 1]
group_d = group_d[group_d['Twin'] == 'N']


print("in area1 there are", len(group_a.index), "children in group_a")
print("in area1 there are", len(group_b.index), "children in group_b")
print("in area1 there are", len(group_c.index), "children in group_c")
print("in area1 there are", len(group_d.index), "children in group_d")
```